# Have JavaScript function output variable as string to use in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, variables

The following JavaScript functions output data plans, the first function `myDataPlan` is called in the second function `dataPlanOutput`.

```
function myDataPlan(networkGroupId, countryCode) {
    data_url = apiURL + '/api/v4/networkGroups/' + networkGroupId + '/plansExt?countryCode=' + countryCode;
    jQuery.getJSON(data_url, function (dataPlan) {
        jQuery.each(dataPlan.list, function (i, list) {
            var currencySymbol = getCurrencySymbol(list.currency); 
            //Price
            var content = '<tr>';
            content += '<td>' + currencySymbol + list.price + '</td>';
            //Data Limits
            content += '<td>' + getDataLimit(list) + '</td>';
            //Data Length
            content += '<td>' + list.validityPeriodInDays + '&nbsp;Days</td>';
            content += '</tr>';
            jQuery(content).appendTo("#dataplan_list");
        });
    });
}

function dataPlanOutput(countryCode) {
    document.getElementById("dataplan_list").innerHTML = "";
    network_url = apiURL + '/api/v4/countries/' + countryCode;
    jQuery.getJSON(network_url, function (networkGroup) {
        jQuery.each(networkGroup.list, function (i, list) {
            var countryName = list.region;
            var networkGroupId = list.networkGroupId;
            myDataPlan(networkGroupId, countryCode);
            document.getElementById('dataplan_list').innerHTML += '<tr><td colspan="3" class="title-h4">' + countryName + '</td></tr>';
        });
    });
}
```

Currently I have  `myDataPlan` printing to the div of #dataplan_list within the function. What I would like it to do is when the function is called it then creates a variable (lets call it `printDataPlan`)that is added to the final line of the `dataPlanOutput` so it looks something like this:

```
document.getElementById('dataplan_list').innerHTML += '<tr><td colspan="3" class="title-h4">' + countryName + '</td></tr>' + printDataPlan;
```

Comment: In the first function, instead of appending content to dataplan_list, can you just return content? And then set the call to myDataPlan equal to your printDataPlan variable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just return the value from myDataPlan?  And then execute that at the end of your `.innerHTML +=` within dataPlanOutput?

```
function myDataPlan(networkGroupId, countryCode) {
data_url = apiURL + '/api/v4/networkGroups/' + networkGroupId + '/plansExt?countryCode=' + countryCode;
jQuery.getJSON(data_url, function (dataPlan) {
    jQuery.each(dataPlan.list, function (i, list) {
        var currencySymbol = getCurrencySymbol(list.currency); 
        //Price
        var content = '<tr>';
        content += '<td>' + currencySymbol + list.price + '</td>';
        //Data Limits
        content += '<td>' + getDataLimit(list) + '</td>';
        //Data Length
        content += '<td>' + list.validityPeriodInDays + '&nbsp;Days</td>';
        content += '</tr>';
        return content;
    });
});
}

function dataPlanOutput(countryCode) {
document.getElementById("dataplan_list").innerHTML = "";
network_url = apiURL + '/api/v4/countries/' + countryCode;
jQuery.getJSON(network_url, function (networkGroup) {
    jQuery.each(networkGroup.list, function (i, list) {
        var countryName = list.region;
        var networkGroupId = list.networkGroupId;
        myDataPlan(networkGroupId, countryCode);
        document.getElementById('dataplan_list').innerHTML += '<tr><td colspan="3" class="title-h4">' + countryName + '</td></tr>' + myDataPlan('var1','var2');
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Ive tried this but I just get a return of undefined?

Comment: but it's not undefined when you append directly within myDataPlan?